# "ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected" when creating a table

Tags: sqlplus

```
SQL> create table sales_order(
  2     ono varchar2(6) check(ono like 'o%'),
  3     cno varchar2(6),
  4     orderdate date not null,
  5     deladder varchar2(30),
  6     sno varchar2(6), deltype char(1) check (deltype in('P','F')),
  7     bill char(1),
  8     delydate date CHECK(delydate in('delydate>orderdate')),
  9     orderstatus varchar2(10) check(orderstatus in('inprocess','fullfilled','
backorder',
 10     'cancelled')),
 11     constraint p5 primary key(ono),
 12     constraint f3 foreign key(sno) references salesman_master(sno)
 13     );
create table sales_order(
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Comment: well since you said you need it asap

Answer (score 1):

Your `delydate` has an invalid `check`. It checks on a `varchar` instead of a `date`.

Try this:

```
create table ...
add constraint delydate_c CHECK(delydate > orderdate)
```

Comment: I HAVE THIS QUERY BRO "DELAYDATE Cannot be lessthan ORDER DATE  " HOW SHOULD I REPRESENT IT PLZ HELP

Comment: its showing this error"delydate date CHECK(delydate > orderdate),
                                         *
OR at line 7:
-02438: Column check constraint cannot reference other columns
"

Comment: ERROR is showing like this for your new answer its not working 
ORA-00904: "DELYDATE": invalid identifier

Comment: Since you are new here: please don't forget to mark your question as answered when any of the answers met your needs.